# An infinite loop

Tags: c, infinite-loop

I'm reading 'The C programming language' and I'm doing exercise 1-18:

```
 Write a program to remove trailing blanks and tabs from each line of input, and to delete entirely blank lines.
```

I wrote a program as follows, but it turns out to be an infinite loop. I used gdb and found that line 38 is conducted infinitely: `if(arr[i] == '\t')`,even though arr[i] == '\t' does not hold. What's wrong with it?

```
01 #include <stdio.h>
02 #define MAXLINE 1000
03 
04 int delete(char arr[],int maxline);
05 int getlines(char arr[], int maxline);
06
07 int main(){
08     char arr[MAXLINE];
09     int len,i;
10     while((len = getlines(arr, MAXLINE)) > 0){
11         if(delete(arr, MAXLINE))
12             printf("%s",arr);
13     }
14     return 0;
15 }
16
17 /* Function getlines is used to input lines */
18 int getlines(char arr[], int maxline){
19    int i = 0,c;
20    while( i < maxline-1 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n'){
21        arr[i] = c;
22        i++;
23    }
24    if( c == '\n'){
25        arr[i] = c;
26        i++;
27    }
28    arr[i] = '\0';
29    return i;
30 }
31
32 /* Function delete is used to delete tab and trailing blanks */
33 int delete(char arr[],int maxline){
34    int i = 0;
35    if(arr[i] == '\n') return 0;  /* if it's a blank line, return 0 */
36    int j;
37    while( arr[i] != '\0'){
38        if(arr[i] == '\t')
39            for( j = i; (arr[j] = arr[j+1]) != '\0'; j++)
40        i++;
41    }
42    for( j = i; j < maxline; j++)
43        arr[j] = arr[j+1];
44    return 1;
45 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop on line 39 is not terminated.

```
for( j = i; (arr[j] = arr[j+1]) != '\0'; j++)
```

so it calls

```
i ++ ;
```

as its body.

At a minimum use:

```
for( j = i; (arr[j] = arr[j+1]) != '\0'; j++) { }
```

Even better, put {} around it:

```
{ for( j = i; (arr[j] = arr[j+1]) != '\0'; j++) { } }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I miss the ';' at the end of the for statement. It's all right now:P

Answer (score 0):

You never get to line 40 which would increment i. That is why you never exit the loop that is starting at line 37.

Answer (score 0):

In the below code, `arr[i] !=  '\0'`, is causing the infinite loop. You are not incrementing `i` properly.

```
while( arr[i] != '\0')
{
    if(arr[i] == '\t')
        for( j = i; (arr[j] = arr[j+1]) != '\0'; j++)
            i++;
}
```

Use below code to delete the tab,

```
while( arr[i] != '\0')
{
    {
        if(arr[i] == '\t')
        for( j = i; (arr[j] = arr[j+1]) != '\0'; j++)
            i++;
    }
    i++; // Increment i here
}
```